# Can I run a 12V rated LED on a 10V rail, +5V to -5V volts?

Tags: led

This might be a dumb question. I can certainly run a 12V rated LED on 10V. These LEDs have built in resistors so the current will just be a bit lower than specified. But can I connect the LED between the +5V and -5V rails? Obviously there will be a 10V potential difference which will make the diode conduct as the forward voltage is only 2.2V, but I just want to check for my sanity. I don't think I've ever connected anything between positive and negative rails like this. The two 5V rails are used for op amps but everything else on this PCB is referenced to ground. There wouldn't be any issues right? That 10V difference would only be used to drive the LED and the op amps.

Comment: why do you mention op amps? ... are they somehow related to the LED?

Comment: @jsotola lol no, just that the two 5V rails exist to power the op amps.

Comment: It would be dimmer than expected but work.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 why dimmer? oh just because its 10V vs 12V?

Comment: Stripleds depend on a string of LEDs to added up to 9 (3W) or 10V (5R) plus current limiting Rs to work up to 14.x V. Yours may be different.

Answer (score 1):

If the LED works on 10 V then  it should work just as well on +-5 V, which is the same thing as far as the LED is concerned.

The only issue might be whether the -5 V rail can supply the extra current required. It may be that the negative supply has been rated to only deliver enough current to run a few op amps, while the positive supply might have a much higher rating to power other devices. The negative supply might also have poorer regulation that could cause noticeable flicker due to voltage variations (which op amps are largely immune to).

If your 'LED' is a single 2.2 V LED with series resistor then a bit lower voltage won't reduce the brightness much, but if it is actually several LEDs in series then a slightly lower voltage could cause a big drop in brightness and higher ripple sensitivity.

Comment: What do you mean about the -5V rail supplying current? It's going to sink the current from the LED.

Comment: Depends on your point of view. A power supply sources current, only in this case it's negative current, which is the same as sinking positive current when the load is 'pulling up' to a positive voltage. Normally when talking about a supply 'sinking' current we mean that a current is being pushed into it from a larger voltage than it produces (positive or negative depending on the power supply polarity).

Comment: @kefffin There's confusion amongst even manufacturers of the best way to present specifications of negative voltages. There's the 'sign, magnitude' brigade, and the Cartesian 'positive is bigger' mob. Both have their advantages. If one seems confusing, try flipping to the other. Often a +/- 5 V supply has a bigger stronger +5 V output than the -5 V output, and we understand that power supplies 'source' power, and so also 'source' current. In the context of the LED, it's sinking current. If asked to sink too much, its cartesian voltage would rise, maybe even to positive, which would be bad!

Comment: @BruceAbbott What do you mean its negative current? It's not negative current. We seem be thinking about different circuits. I've been referring to an LED and resistor in series, high side in 5V and low side is -5V instead of ground. Current flows from +5V through the diode to -5V. That means the current is positive.

Comment: @Neil_UK Didn't know dual power supplies were unbalanced like that. Yeah I mean I think I understand what you're saying, you can just say one part of the supply +5V is sourcing current and the other part -5V is sinking it. I don't understand your last sentence though.

Comment: @kefffin you haven't told us anything about your power supply except the voltage, so I had to consider things that might not apply to it in my answer (if you want a more specific answer then post the schematic, specs, and/or a photo of your power supply).

Comment: @kefffin A PC power supply for instance might supply 25 A from +5V, but only 1 A (or -1 A if you like) from the -5V (you didn't tell us whether you were using a bench, PC, or another type of supply). If you put a 1.5 A load between +/- 5V, then the -5V output could be pulled up to higher than 0V, which would reverse bias anything connected to -5 V and ground, with possibly bad consequences for both the -5 V supply, and the thing connected to it.

Comment: @kefffin What Neil meant by negative current is that, if you define the current as going *out* of the -5 volt terminal, the current you measure will be negative.

Comment: @kefffin -- The other way you can see negative current is that we are moving electron-holes. This is akin to bubbles rising in a pool. What's being moved? It looks like air. But an equal amount of water is actually moving downward. A mind-bender, I know. Hope this helps.